# How to eliminate other possible solutions when doing DC analysis of Analog CMOS

Tags: integrated-circuit, cmos

This is my LTspice schematic.

[image]

I want to calculate \$V_{D5}\$, \$V_{D1}\$, \$V_{o}\$ with **vpasolve** of matlab. (body effect is omitted)

$$I_D = K \frac{W} {L} (|V_{GS}| - |V_{th}|)^2 (1 + \lambda |V_{DS}|)$$

The following is my matlab code for this.
I have tried to assume it works in saturation region.

```
syms Vd5 Vd1 Vo

Vg1 = 0.5;
eq1 = 45*0.28^2*(1+0.14*(1.8-Vd5));
eq2 = 45*(Vd5 - Vg1 - 0.42)^2*(1+0.14*(Vd5 - Vd1));
eq3 = 180*(Vd1 - 0.4)^2*(1+0.1*Vd1);
eq4 = 45*(Vd5 - Vg1 - 0.42)^2*(1+0.14*(Vd5 - Vo));
eq5 = 180*(Vd1 - 0.4)^2*(1+0.1*Vo);

assume(Vd5,'real')
assume(Vd5 > 0)

assume(Vd1,'real')
assume(Vd1 > 0)

assume(Vo,'real')
assume(Vo > 0)
sols=vpasolve([eq1 == eq2 + eq4, eq1 == eq3 + eq5, eq2 == eq3, eq4 == eq5], [Vd5 Vd1 Vo])

sols.Vd5
sols.Vd1
sols.Vo
```

However, I get four solutions for each of them.

$$
V_{D5}\\
0.71344432404311890453319743751794\\
 1.1187983792156107381232495588654\\
0.71045661574218931843791077163816\\
 1.1163074481576831005801671170109
$$

$$
V_{D1}\\
0.29527690618454959297640091709984\\
0.50110568892034423447002647073843\\
0.50369771677840608850545439819988\\
0.29788531456890030501286382283015
$$

$$
V_{o}\\
0.29527690618454959297640091709984\\
0.50110568892034423447002647073843\\
0.50369771677840608850545439819988\\
0.29788531456890030501286382283015
$$

We know that \$|V_{DS}| > |V_{GT}|\$. However, it is still impossible to eliminate any of this four solution results.

The following is the asc file from LTSpice.

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 880 680
WIRE 16 -160 -48 -160
WIRE 336 -160 16 -160
WIRE 640 -160 336 -160
WIRE 320 -144 64 -144
WIRE 448 -144 320 -144
WIRE -48 -112 -48 -160
WIRE 16 -112 -48 -112
WIRE 16 -48 16 -64
WIRE -32 -32 -80 -32
WIRE 16 -32 16 -48
WIRE 16 -32 -32 -32
WIRE 48 -32 16 -32
WIRE 96 -32 48 -32
WIRE -192 -16 -272 -16
WIRE -128 -16 -192 -16
WIRE 288 -16 144 -16
WIRE -32 16 -32 -32
WIRE -32 16 -80 16
WIRE 48 16 48 -32
WIRE 96 16 48 16
WIRE -576 64 -576 0
WIRE -416 64 -416 0
WIRE -272 64 -272 -16
WIRE 288 64 288 -16
WIRE 448 64 448 -144
WIRE 640 64 640 -160
WIRE -80 96 -80 64
WIRE 16 96 -80 96
WIRE 96 112 96 64
WIRE 144 112 96 112
WIRE -80 128 -80 96
WIRE 96 128 96 112
WIRE -80 176 -160 176
WIRE 176 176 96 176
WIRE 16 208 16 96
WIRE 16 208 -32 208
WIRE 48 208 16 208
WIRE -576 240 -576 144
WIRE -416 240 -416 144
WIRE -416 240 -576 240
WIRE -272 240 -272 144
WIRE -272 240 -416 240
WIRE -160 240 -160 176
WIRE -160 240 -272 240
WIRE -80 240 -80 224
WIRE -80 240 -160 240
WIRE 96 240 96 224
WIRE 96 240 -80 240
WIRE 176 240 176 176
WIRE 176 240 96 240
WIRE 288 240 288 144
WIRE 288 240 176 240
WIRE 448 240 448 144
WIRE 448 240 288 240
WIRE 640 240 640 144
WIRE 640 240 448 240
WIRE -576 256 -576 240
FLAG -576 256 0
FLAG 336 -160 VDD
FLAG 320 -144 VB
FLAG -192 -16 VG1
FLAG 288 -16 VG2
FLAG 16 96 VD1
FLAG -576 0 Vicm
FLAG -416 0 Vid
FLAG 144 112 Vo
IOPIN 144 112 Out
FLAG 16 -48 VD5
SYMBOL nmos4 48 128 R0
WINDOW 123 56 100 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M4
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH
SYMBOL nmos4 -32 128 M0
WINDOW 123 56 100 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M3
SYMATTR Value NMOS-SH
SYMBOL pmos4 144 64 R180
WINDOW 3 -107 24 Left 2
WINDOW 123 -106 -4 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M2
SYMBOL pmos4 -128 64 M180
WINDOW 3 -106 15 Left 2
WINDOW 123 -106 43 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M1
SYMBOL pmos4 64 -64 R180
WINDOW 123 96 35 Left 2
SYMATTR Value2 l=1u w=20u
SYMATTR InstName M5
SYMATTR Value PMOS-SH
SYMBOL voltage -576 48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vicm
SYMATTR Value 0.5
SYMBOL voltage -416 48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName Vid
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL voltage 448 48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VB
SYMATTR Value 1.1
SYMBOL voltage 640 48 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName VDD
SYMATTR Value 1.8
SYMBOL bv -272 48 R0
WINDOW 3 -98 210 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vicm)+V(Vid)/2
SYMATTR InstName B1
SYMBOL bv 288 48 R0
WINDOW 3 -103 209 Left 2
SYMATTR Value V=V(Vicm)-V(Vid)/2
SYMATTR InstName B2
TEXT -264 -240 Left 2 !.MODEL NMOS-SH nmos(kp=180u,vto=0.4, lambda = {0.1/1}, gamma = 0.5, phi = 0.7)
TEXT -264 -216 Left 2 !.MODEL PMOS-SH pmos(kp=45u,vto=-0.42, lambda = {0.14/1}, gamma = 0.5, phi = 0.7)
TEXT -264 -264 Left 2 !;dc Vicm 0 1.8 0.01
TEXT -264 -288 Left 2 !;tf V(Vo) Vid
TEXT -256 -320 Left 2 !.op
```

Comment: It seems like there might be a mistake somewhere, but it's a bit difficult to double-check your work since you've presented the equations without any explanation.

Comment: @internet I will explain it now.

Comment: First of all, any answers you get using these simplified models will only be good to maybe 2-3 digits of accuracy. So you really only have two answers, not four. VD5 is 0.71 or 1.12. VD1 is 0.30 or 0.50. VO is 0.30 or 0.50. What solutions do you get from spice? How do you know that there aren't two stable operating points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problem is your assumption:

$$
I_D = K \frac{W} {L} (|V_{GS}| - |V_{th}|)^2 (1 + \lambda |V_{DS}|)
$$

This is only valid if:

$$
(|V_{GS}| > |V_{th}|)
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please have a look at another question when you have time? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699655/how-to-calculate-this-close-loop-gain-for-this-ota-circuit