# How to calculate this close loop gain for this OTA circuit?

Tags: ota

Try to find close loop gain of the following is the circuit (\$\gamma = 0\$,
body effect can be omitted).
[image]

$$Q_1 = Q_2, 
Q_3 =Q_4$$

Here is what I have tried to solve.

1. We have to break the loop and add a test voltage.

[image]

For this 4 transistor OTA (Operational transconductance amplifiers).

This gain equation for this OTA can be found from the book [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), Page 154.

$$\frac{V_x} {V_t} = -g_{m1,2} (r_{O2} \parallel r_{O4}) \frac{2 g_{m3,4} r_{O4} + 1} {2 (g_{m3,4} r_{O4} + 1)}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_x} {V_t} \approx -g_{m1,2} (r_{O2} \parallel r_{O4}) \tag{1}$$

For nmos Q5.

$$(V_x - V_{r}) g_{m5} - \frac{V_{r}} {r_{o5}} = V_{r} s C_L$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{r}} {V_x} = \frac{g_{m5}} {g_{m5} + 1/r_{o5} + s C_L} \tag{2}$$

Combine these **(1)** and **(2)** equation together

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{x}} {V_{t}}  \frac{V_{r}} {V_x} = \frac{V_r} {V_t}  \approx -g_{m1,2} (r_{O2} \parallel r_{O4}) \frac{g_{m5}} {g_{m5} + 1/r_{o5} + s C_L}$$

We can see from the gain it's negative feedback.

$$A_{v, close} =  \frac{ \mbox{$\Large g_{m1,2} (r_{O2} \parallel r_{O4}) \frac{g_{m5}} {g_{m5} + 1/r_{o5} + s C_L} $}} {\mbox{$\Large 1 + g_{m1,2} (r_{O2} \parallel r_{O4}) \frac{g_{m5}} {g_{m5} + 1/r_{o5} + s C_L} $}}$$

Comment: It's a unity gain follower if you look how the feedback works.

Comment: @Andyaka Is my close loop gain analysis correct?

Comment: I just looked at the circuit and concluded it was a unity gain follower. In other words, from what I saw, it doesn't need a calculation. Of course, if you want to add context to your question then, my simplistic answer may not be sufficient but, as a first pass, it is.

Comment: @Andyaka Do you have an equation for this close loop gain?

Comment: Does "unity gain buffer" not imply anything to you? Also, why do you use the term OTA?

Comment: @Andyaka OTA is just for this four transistors in the left (Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4).  I don't know what you mean unity gain buffer.

Comment: Kile, the circuit is not an operational transconductance amplifier once you have applied voltage feedback. A unity gain buffer has a non-inverting gain of unity.

Comment: You presented your calculation. What is your question then? Do you think that there is an error in your calculation somewhere, or do you have any questions about a specific part of your calculation?

Comment: @internet I have doubts on close loop gain. Because close loop gain is around 1 in my calculation. Can you confirm it whether it's correct or wrong?

Comment: @kile I haven't calculated it, but it looks good to me. The closed-loop gain should be around 1 since it's a voltage follower.

Comment: @internet could you take a look at my analysis and formula when you have time?

Comment: @kile your analysis looks good.

Comment: @internet Thanks!